# C# how to Parse stored procedure String

Tags: c#, regex, par

I have a Query string from client application. It comes with all parameters like

```
string query="PROCS.DBO.APP_2370_ANALYST_S 'ABC' , 'TESTDATA' , 100";
```

In Server, I made a function(Util.getParametersFromString)  to parse string from client application to make parameter object Array using string.Split function. 
I used ',' and ' ' as separator to make object array.

And I execute db procedure by using below code

```
 object[] parameters = Util.getParametersFromString(query); 
 DbCommand cmd = dbconnection.GetStoredProcCommand("PROCS.DBO.APP_2370_ANALYST_S",     parameters);
```

I works well if parameter string doesn't contain  comma or single quotation mark. 
If one of parameter string have one or more comma or single quotaion mark. 
Like below

```
string query="PROCS.DBO.APP_2370_ANALYST_S 'A,B,C' , 'Hi, Sam 'The Legend' Brown  was here ' , 100";
```

parameter array didn't come correctly.  I didn't know how to parse string correctly in this

situation. Please give me advice to solve this problem

I am not good at english. So I am so sorry If I didn't write my question correctly

Regards,
Park

Answer (score 1):

You can escape the single quotes - `'` becomes `''`:

```
string query="PROCS.DBO.APP_2370_ANALYST_S 'A,B,C' , 'Hi, Sam ''The Legend'' Brown  was here ' , 100";
```

As for the problem with a comma - it depends on how your function is written. You will have to escape the comma and make sure your function is aware of this escape sequence.

Answer (score 1):

If both parameters of your query string are as flexible as your example, and you cannot change the way this string is generated as suggested in [Oded's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130569/c-how-to-parse-stored-procedure-string/3130584#3130584), you have a problem.

The query `"PROCS.DBO.APP_2370_ANALYST_S 'ABC' , 'ABC' , 'ABC' , 100"` for example, could be interpreted as having the first parameter `"'ABC' , 'ABC'"` and second parameter `"ABC"` or vice versa.

If, on the other hand, your first parameter may not contain `'`s, then you could identify the first parameter by looking between the first two `'`s, and the second parameter by falling between the third and the last `'`.